# GridSearchCV Decrease performance RF

Tags: machine-learning, python, regression, random-forest, grid-search

Can Gridsearchcv params perform worst than default RF?

RF with default values performs `rmse_train=4886`,`r^2_train=0.84`, `rmse_test=11008`,`r^2_test=0.22`.
RF after GridSearchCV tuning performs worst on train set (`rmse_train=9104`,`r^2_train=0.45`, `rmse_test=11091`,`r^2_test=0.21`). This is the code (my first ML algorithm implementation)

```py
#data
features = pd.read_csv("dati_nn.csv")
labels = np.array(features['Cost_damage']) #regression problem
features = features.drop('Cost_damage', axis=1)
features = np.array(features)
train_features, test_features, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(features, labels, test_size=0.2, random_state = 123)

#RF default
rf = RandomForestRegressor(random_state = 123)
rf.fit(train_features, train_labels)
pred_train = rf.predict(train_features)
predictions = rf.predict(test_features)
# compute rmse and r_score
rmse_train = np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(train_labels, pred_train))
rmse_test = np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(test_labels, predictions))
r2_train = r2_score(train_labels, pred_train)
r2_test = r2_score(test_labels, predictions)

#GridSearch
param_grid = {
    'bootstrap': [True], 
    'max_depth': [20, 30], 
    'max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt'], 
    'min_samples_leaf': [1, 2, 3], 
    'min_samples_split': [5, 8, 10, 12], 
    'n_estimators': [500, 600, 700, 800, 1000] 
}
rf = RandomForestRegressor(random_state = 123)
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator = rf, 
                           param_grid = param_grid, 
                           scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error', 
                           cv = 10, 
                           n_jobs = -1,
                           verbose = 2 
                          )
grid_search.fit(train_features, train_labels)

best_grid = grid_search.best_estimator_
pred_train = best_grid.predict(train_features)
predictions = best_grid.predict(test_features)
#rmse and r2_score as above
```

In my opinion, the code is correct but I don't understand why rmse grows.
I searched for many days on the internet to find an answer...no success. I tried to use `RandomizedSearchCV`, same problem.
Any suggest? Is my workflow correct?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are different for a valid reason

*The standalone model is overfitting. You can see that with `r2score` of 84 Vs 22*.

The reason for that is, the standalone model goes to full depth and hence overfit the train data and badly fit the test data.

> **max_depthint, default=None**
>
> *The maximum depth of the tree. If None, then nodes are expanded until all leaves are pure or until all leaves contain less than min_samples_split samples.*

While with CV, you have parm for `max_depth`. *Hence bad but Truth*.

Comment: Oh, it makes sense...with `r2=0.84` I didn't think about overfitting. So, the steps are correct but I've to play with hyperparms. Can be useful run `RandomizedSearchCV` before Gridsearch to limit the hyperparms range? like in this post [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/hyperparameter-tuning-the-random-forest-in-python-using-scikit-learn-28d2aa77dd74)